# How i can update or install latest version of IOS in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, app-store, react-native-ios

Am using Xcode 10.3, i want to use latest IOS for target devices in my xcode 10.3, how i can install or update IOS without update Xcode 10.3. I tried to download IOS_SDK file and IOS_DeviceSupport file and paste it in xcode and restart xcode but am not able to use latest IOS Versions. IS there any other option to use latest os version in Xcode 10.3.

Comment: According to me it is not possible. Latest iOS SDK come along with latest Xcode. You can update your Xcode and Mac-OS.

Comment: Upgrading to the latest XCode is required in order to be able to test the latest iOS versions